# Why Lambda Function in C++0x return type has to be auto?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, lambda

I am a newbie in C++. I was just trying few small code snippet to understand lambda functions compiled using GCC 4.6.3 with `-std=c++0x`. I know it is not the best for C++0x but it supports lambda expressions.
I have wrote this:

```
int main(){
    int val1 = 0, val2 = 0;
    std::cout << "Enter Value1" << '\n';
    std::cin >> val1;
    std::cout << "Enter Value2" << '\n';
    std::cin >> val2;
    auto result = [&val1, &val2](){return (val1 + val2);};
    std::cout << "Result: " << [](int x, int y){return(x + y);}(32, 46) << '\n';
    //std::cout << "Result: " << [&val1, &val2](){return (val1 + val2) ;} << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

My first question is why do i have to define `result` as `auto` when i already know the expected(implicit) result will be `int`?
In the commented line of code i am getting an error `error: cannot bind ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’`.
Can you please tell me why it is happening?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You seem to be getting confused between the result of the function and the function itself. On this line

```
auto result = [&val1, &val2](){return (val1 + val2);};
```

you are creating a lambda function (on the right side of the `=`), and assigning it to a variable called `result`.  The `auto` there is for the type of the variable holding the lambda function, not the return type of the lambda function.

If you wanted to make the return type be explicit, it would be done like this:

```
auto result = [&val1, &val2]() -> int {return (val1 + val2);};
```

If you wanted to make the type of `result` more explicit, you can use `std::function`:

```
std::function<int()> result = [&val1, &val2]() {return (val1 + val2);};
```

Also, since `result` is a function, you would use `result` like this:

```
std::cout << result() << "\n";
```

Comment: I am suspecting this lambda expressions to be something like one line functions in Python so doesn't then result should be a return variable & auto should be saying like return type is some (void*)? It's like calling result = func(int x, int y); where func definition is int func(int, int); ?? Also std::function is a wrapper which will make things complicated, don't you think so?

Comment: Up vote for increasing my information about lambda expressions. :)

Comment: @AshankPanwar: Lambdas are like nameless functions, but you seem to be getting confused between the result of the function and the function itself.

Comment: I got it but my confusion was more about why can't i just define `int result` instead of `auto result`? Since i know the return type will be an `int` considering even if compiler will do implicit conversions. But i think it was more on my understanding of `auto` keyword as such.

Comment: @AshankPanwar:  I've added some detail to my answer that may make it more clear.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, `result`  is a function (note that you do not execute the anonymous function). In the line

```
std::cout << "Result: " << [&val1, &val2](){return (val1 + val2) ;} << '\n';
```

you are trying to output a function, not the result of applying the function. Change it to

```
std::cout << "Result: " << [&val1, &val2](){return (val1 + val2) ;}() << '\n';
```

and it prints out the sum of `val1` and `val2`.

Comment: It's not a function pointer, it's an instance of the closure type created by the lambda expression.

Comment: Oh ok so i have just return the definition but for calling this anonymous function i need to enter parenthesis. Thanks.. :)